# Compile for ARM Cortex M3 using standard GCC?

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m

Is it possible to compile C/C++ code for the ARM Cortex M3 (LPC1768) using vanilla GCC with the `--target` switch, or will I need to compile GCC, binutils, etc to do this?

Comment: You can try this if you are using linux.
http://www.eluaproject.net/doc/v0.8/en_tc_cortex.html

Answer (score 10):

As already said, those are not your only two options. I suggest trying this toolchain prepared by ARM engineers: [GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) . It's specifically tailored for Cortex-M and Cortex-R cores, and it doesn't require registration to download it.

Comment: I find the new download page for this toolchain to be much easier to use, and it gives me more peace of mind knowing it comes from arm.com:  https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Answer (score 4):

You can find an excellent series of tutorial style blog posts [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com), for example [this one](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/using-codesourcery-bare-metal-toolchain-for-cortex-m3/) about bare metal programming for the M3.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeSourcery G++](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/) supports a wide range of ARM processors including Cortex-M3. Its also free unless you need professional support.

Comment: well there is a lite version, and you need to read the license agreement.

Comment: llvm, though, cross compiles out of the box, you can use -march=arm to build for arm.  Depends on what you are doing though

Comment: the cortex-m3 is thumb/thumb2 only so be careful to specify the processor type when compiling (with gcc), otherwise it will default to arm instructions.  and my comment about llvm -march=arm will build arm it might be -march=thumb to build for thumb.

Comment: And make sure you do not specify -mthumb-interwork when you compile for Cortex-M, otherwise you will get ARM32 code in there, which your MCU will not understand, thus your program will crash.